# How to auto fix common linting errors reported via syntastic?

Tags: quickfix, filetype-javascript, plugin-syntastic

I started using **syntastic** plugin with **vim** to report lint errors in my `javascript` code.

I also integrated **eslint** with **syntastic**, and it shows me nice errors, warnings in case they are present as per rules written in my **.eslintrc** file.

Is there any way in which I can fix some common errors e.g missing semi-colon, missing space etc with a key-stroke?

**Edit:**

I have found that **eslint** has an option

```
  --fix Automatically fix problems
```

which can be used for such cases.
I need to run this command to let eslint fix those issues

```
eslint --fix -c myconfig file.js
```

I want to know how that can be integrated with **vim**?

Comment: 1. You don't need that plugin for syntax checking. 2. Auto fixing errors is a very bad idea.

Comment: Not all errors I am talking about errors such as space around =, space around if block, indentation etc. These are errors related to code styles, not actual errors.

Comment: The short answer is yes, of course you can. You'd need to define a custom function to parse the lines in the quickfix looking for the specific errors that you wanted to fix, and execute a command based on those errors. You could easily use the quickfix to take you to the location of each error as well. You'd then map the function to a keystroke. `map <C-j> call Function()<CR>` But this would be a very custom tailored function that you would need to write to suit your needs. And romainl's point is that if you do something wrong you can easily end up doing more harm than good. Caution is advised

Comment: Use a pretty printer to enforce consistent formatting.

Comment: _I need to run this command to let eslint fix those issues_ - I'm handing you the gun since you're asking, but it's still pointing at your foot: [fixmyjs](https://github.com/ruanyl/vim-fixmyjs) (first hit on Google), and also see a [related answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37617895).  You really should consider changing these to run `vimdiff` against the original and the patched versions, rather than replace the original.

Comment: IDEs all support some kind of automatic formating, I don't understand the hate here. My company uses a pre-commit hook to `eslint --fix`, I'd much rather have this at the editor level.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the comments be aware of the consequences this modification has to you work environment (know exactly which eslint rules you use to "fix" things).

To answer your question: adding the option to the eslint execution with syntactic is [straight forward](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqargs). Simply add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
" execute eslint with --fix flag
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = ['--fix']
```

But as eslint is executed on the file after vim writes its buffer to the file, vim doesn't know about the fixes eslint does. So somehow vim has to load the file again (the manual way would be to simply type `:e` in normal/command mode). To do that, we can use the [autoread](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autoread') option together with [checktime](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:checktime):

```
" enable autoread to reload any files from files when checktime is called and
" the file is changed
set autoread
```

To call checktime we can use an [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) which gets executed every time a buffer is written to a file. But as syntactic is using its own autocmd on same event `BufWritePost` we have to add our autocmd after syntactic adds its own. I found that this is the case when we add our autocmd on `VimEnter`:

```
" add an autocmd after vim started to execute checktime for *.js files on write
au VimEnter *.js au BufWritePost *.js checktime
```

So after adding all three parts to your `.vimrc` vim should behave as expected (lint and autocorrect on file save `:w`).

Answer (score 7):

The solution given in Jepz's answer didn't completely work for me. `eslint` was correctly called with the `--fix` option. However, maybe it's because of internals that have changed, but it seems like `checktime` was called before the end of `eslint --fix`, so the file reloading didn't work properly, triggering a `file has changed, are you sure you want to write to it?` on the next save.

However, by digging into issues, I've discovered a hidden hook that seems to trigger after the Syntastic checks have completed, called `SyntasticCheckHook` ([source](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/1678)).

With this, you can simply call `checktime` after the Syntastic checks have run.

Here is my final code:

```
set autoread

let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']

" autofix with eslint
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = ['--fix']
function! SyntasticCheckHook(errors)
  checktime
endfunction
```

---

*Edit: I've personally switched to `ALE` for linting, which supports autofixing natively.*