# Fix a specific eslint error automatically

Tags: key-bindings

I often get an `eslint` error in a Javascript file, which is trivial to fix - for example, trailing spaces or incorrect indentation:

[image]

In this case, I would have to `^XX` to navigate to the beginning of the line and delete two spaces. Not the end of the world, but some cases - like long lines that needs to be broken - are more cumbersome. Note that I am not looking for [a complete auto-fix for the file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8381/how-to-auto-fix-common-linting-errors-reported-via-syntastic), just a quick fix apply for the current highlighted problem.

Is there a way to define a key binding that would auto-fix the current `eslint` error, if possible?

Comment: you should check your `tabstop`, `shiftwidth`, `softtabstop` and perhaps `shiftround` option

Comment: Will do! That would probably help me avoid this specific problem, but would it help me with auto-fixing with `eslint`?

Comment: for the given example, a simple `<<` should work, if your cursor is on the correct line

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt True, but there are other, more complicated errors, and I'm looking for a more general auto-fix solution for the current error.

Comment: i am not sure, there exists such a general auto-fixable solution. My guess is, you need a custom-tailored solution for your specific requirements, that could be a function called after your linter is finished and tries to fix some easy problems or does some kind of pretty-printing before running the syntax checker.

Comment: @AdamMatan Check this question which may get you what you need. It looks like ALE is the answer. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8381/how-to-auto-fix-common-linting-errors-reported-via-syntastic